# SQL Error 1016 - Inner Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I'm trying to add inner joins to old SQL code to make it run more efficiently. But when I added them and tried to execute I get this error:

```
1016, Line 12 Outer join operators cannot be specified in a query containing joined tables
```

Here's the query:

```
select a.s_purchase_order as order_id, 
a.order_type, 
a.nobackorder, 
a.order_note, 
a.note, 
a.rqst_dlvry_date, 
b.customer_name ,
c.store_name,
(c.store_name + ',' + isnull(c.address1 + ',', ' ') +  isnull(c.city + ',', ' ') +  isnull(c.state_cd+ ',', ' ')  + isnull( c.zipcode, ' ')) as store_info, 
d.supplier_account
from VW_CustomerOrder a, Customer b, Store c, eligible_supplier d
where a.customer = c.customer
and a.store = c.store
and a.customer = b.customer
and c.customer *= d.customer
and c.store *= d.store
and a.supplier *= d.supplier
and a.purchase_order = @order_id
and a.customer = @customer_id
and a.store=@store_id
and a.supplier = @supplier_id
```

Any idea what's causing it? I'm guessing it has something to do with the isnull?

Comment: Those **really** should be written in ANSI syntax, such as `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` syntax, instead of in the `WHERE` clause. I also sincerely doubt the `store_info` line is causing the problem; did you try removing it to see if you still get the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?  It replaces your commas between your tables with `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`

```
select a.s_purchase_order as order_id, 
    a.order_type, 
    a.nobackorder, 
    a.order_note, 
    a.note, 
    a.rqst_dlvry_date, 
    b.customer_name ,
    c.store_name,
    (c.store_name + ',' + isnull(c.address1 + ',', ' ') +  isnull(c.city + ',', ' ') +  isnull(c.state_cd+ ',', ' ')  + isnull( c.zipcode, ' ')) as store_info, 
    d.supplier_account
from VW_CustomerOrder a
INNER JOIN Customer b
    ON a.customer = b.customer
INNER JOIN Store c
    ON a.customer = c.customer
    and a.store = c.store
LEFT JOIN eligible_supplier d
    ON c.customer = d.customer
    and c.store = d.store
    and a.supplier = d.supplier
where a.purchase_order = @order_id
    and a.customer = @customer_id
    and a.store=@store_id
    and a.supplier = @supplier_id
```

Comment: Interesting, your re-write makes it clear that all the joins are also specified by the parameters.

Comment: This did the trick! And it seems to be moving a lot faster now! Thanks so much! I actually learned a little more about joins just by comparing what you did to what I used to have...thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

If you left your "*=" join operators in the code after you converted it to ANSI syntax, that would explain your error.  Use = for all equality tests when using ANSI syntax -- the type of your `JOIN` should be explicit in the `JOIN` declaration itself (`INNER`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, etc.)